# Can I achieve linear (or close to) complexity concatenating strings without allocation?

Tags: c#, c++, string

```
{
   std::string s = "this is a string ";
   std::string res = std::string();
   int sLength = s.length();
   for(int i = 0; i < sLength; i++)
      res += s[i];
}
```

I would imagine this C++ is strictly linear in complexity (with regard to character allocation), as opposed to the quadratic complexity of the equivalent in C#.

However, the fact that in this case, memory is not allocated beforehand, are we actually looking at quadratic complexity as well ? If yes, would allocation of a char array help us to achieve linear complexity ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question? Are you under the impression that each concatenation will force another allocation of `size  = previous_size + 1`? That isn't how it works.

Comment: 1. StringBuilder. 2. in C# this would take the same amount of memory. The GC will eat up all the extra alocations

Comment: @CoryKramer I considered it as a possibility at least.

Comment: @AK_ so you're saying both C++ and C# implementation of this will be quadratic.

Comment: @Franklin No. both would be linear. for different reasons.

Comment: @Franklin also you should clarify whether you are talking about space or time complexity

Comment: @AK_ I thought, disregarding memory deallocation, that space and time complexity would match. What about C#'s string immutability as opposed to C++ std's string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve linear complexity by calling `std::string::reserve`. This would prevent re-allocations as the string grows:

```
std::string s = "this is a string ";
std::string res = "what is this? ";
res.reserve(s.length() + res.length());

for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
   res += s[i];
```

Obviously you wouldn't concatenate strings like that in real life.

Answer (score 1):

According to [cppr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D), adding a character to a string has constant complexity (although I think this carries an implicit "amortized", as for [`string::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/push_back)).

So your code already has linear complexity.

If you care about the allocation cost and have an upper bound for the size beforehand, you can also just [`reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve) enough space to avoid any reallocation and copying of the string. Then, not even a plain `char` buffer should beat your performance (significantly).

Comment: +1 ; thanks. so while both with/without "reserve" provide linear complexity, "reserve" would show a tiny practical improvement.

Comment: @Franklin If tiny or not is subject to measurement, but the complexity is the same.